# Returning string as a HTML object in XSL StyleSheet

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have XML like below:

```
<Test>
   <Content>
      <innerHtml>
         <div style="font-size:13px;">This letter should be wrap by div element.</div>
      </innerHtml>
   </Content>
</Test>
```

In XML stylesheet I call this content like below:

```
<xsl:value-of select="innerHtml"/>
```

And problem occurs here. What I want is to print "innerHtml" node's content as a HTML object, not a string. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//innerHtml"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="innerHtml">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

It just necessary to add disable-output-escaping attribute and set it as "yes" like below:

**`<xsl:value-of select="innerHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>`**